# clear client collection on route change

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I've been struggling with the following issue in Meteor + iron router:

I have a page (route) that has a subscription to a mongo collection

on that page, I have some logic which relies on a cursor querying the collection, also utilizing an observeChanges handler (namely, I'm running a search on that collection)

the problem in this case is the collection is being preserved in the client throughout route changes, which causes 2 unwanted effects:

1) the collection isn't necessarily needed outside that route, meaning i'm wasting client RAM (the collection, or even a subset of it, is likely to be quite big)

2) whenever i go back to that route, I want to start off with an empty subset for the observeChanges handler to work properly.

Any advice on how to clear the mirrored collection? (using the Collection._collection.remove({}) hack is bad practice, and doesn't even solve the problem)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved this by storing the subscription handles. used them to unsubscribe the data (i.e. subscription_handle.stop() ) on template.destroyed()